# Can RemoteObjects be used with Granites´s Tide to enable Lazy Loading?

Tags: spring, hibernate, apache-flex, cairngorm, graniteds

We have a Spring+Hibernate+Mysql+Flex/Cairngorm(2)/BlazeDS application. We need to update this application so it can scale better, specifically we need to use the lazy loading feature. So we decided to migrate from BlazeDS to Granite Data Service. We have:

1.- Added the ant gas3 generation tool task for automatic synchronization between domain objects

2.- We have a working application that loads the first level of our graphs, but not deeper objects of the graph.

Our flex project uses RemoteObjects. I understand that to be able to use Lazy Loading we need tide. To use tide api, we would need to change a bunch of code. **My question is, can I use RemoteObjects and Tide so I can get Lazy Loading without changing our Flex code, just the configuration files ?**

Comment: I've not used Tide yet, but as I understand the docs it's not possible to enable lazy loading just by configuation. GraniteDS is pretty well documented, reading the Tide part might answer your question: http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16875692

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. You need Tide to manage your entities (it has its own cache which ensures that an already known entity is not duplicated in memory) and the lazy-loading (to produce custom queries thanks to the Tide Remote layer to fetch data from the backend) and you need on the server-side a java framework for IOC (Spring, Seam, Guice...) and of course a persistent framework (Hibernate, EJB3...).

Or you can fork granite code to roll your own solution... Not that easy.